# How do I disable an action in a nested listview if there is no record?

Tags: xaf

I have a PopUpWindowShowAction that operates on the current record.

If there is no current record then I want the action disabled.

This is because if there is no record the PopUpWindowShowAction will fail.

Here is my simplified controller

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Editors;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class JobWorkflowController : ViewController
    {
        PopupWindowShowAction actWorkflow;
    

        public JobWorkflowController()
        {

             
            TargetObjectType = typeof(IWorkflow);
            actWorkflow = new PopupWindowShowAction(this, "Workflow", "Admin") 
            { AcceptButtonCaption = string.Empty, ActionMeaning = ActionMeaning.Accept, CancelButtonCaption = null, Caption = "Workflow", ConfirmationMessage = null, ImageName = "Workflow", Shortcut = "F7", ToolTip = null };
            actWorkflow.CustomizePopupWindowParams += actWorkflow_CustomizePopupWindowParams_1;

            actWorkflow.Execute += actWorkflow_Execute_1;
            actWorkflow.Cancel += actWorkflow_Cancel;

        }


        private void actWorkflow_CustomizePopupWindowParams_1(object sender, CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs e)
        {
            if (View.CurrentObject is not IWorkflow wf)
            {
                // causes an error because the view is not set
              
                return;
            }
             
            // code to create the popup view
        }

        private void actWorkflow_Execute_1(object sender, PopupWindowShowActionExecuteEventArgs e)
        {
           // code
        }

        private void actWorkflow_Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // code
        }

        protected override void OnActivated()
        {
            base.OnActivated();
            View.CurrentObjectChanged += View_CurrentObjectChanged;
            View_CurrentObjectChanged(View, new EventArgs());
        }

        private void View_CurrentObjectChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            actWorkflow.Enabled["HasCurrent"]=   View.CurrentObject != null;
        }
        protected override void OnDeactivated()
        {
            View.CurrentObjectChanged -= View_CurrentObjectChanged;
            base.OnDeactivated();
        }
        
    }
}
```

The  View_CurrentObjectChanged event fires but the action does not disable.

[Update]

I tried Michael's suggestion but the action des not disable.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your constructor

```
actWorkflow.SelectionDependencyType = SelectionDependencyType.RequireSingleObject
```

And it will only be active when a single object is selected. If you'd like to have one or more objects selected it's:

```
actWorkflow.SelectionDependencyType = SelectionDependencyType.RequireMultipleObjects;
```

You'll have no need to subscribe to the CurrentObjectChanged event.

Comment: If this doesn't work, that is weird. Can you please provide your constructor. It's also weird it is working, without adding the actions to the Actions property.